# Olive oil - healthy as a substitute, or in its own right?

Tags: nutrition, diet

There are many articles about extra virgin olive oil being healthy - for example [here](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/extra-virgin-olive-oil#section2). This implies, at least, that replacing other fats in the diet (such as butter or other vegetable oils) with olive oil is beneficial. But is olive oil also beneficial to health when consumed in larger amounts? Assuming it is not contributing too many calories and leading to an unhealthy weight.

I really love the taste of olive oil, and enjoy snacks like bread with olive oil, or just using it as a dressing on lots of things. Is this healthy (because olive oil is healthy) or unhealthy (because, even though it is a "good" oil, having a larger fat intake is still bad)?

Comment: This is a good question at a fundamental level, but the reality is that there are many schools of thought on these elements of nutrition, and the answer will end up being a matter of opinion.  I know renowned physician scientists who disagree with each other on this point.  Some even suggest that any processed oil is not ideal, and all oils in our diet should come from consuming whole foods like nuts. The best answer is likely going to be that it depends on the rest of your diet.

Comment: Healthiest and good for you are not the same.   Many cardiologist believe you should still limit total fat.

Comment: @Bennet, could you give an estimation of "larger fat intake" (in grams or percents of calorie intake) you are worrying about?

Comment: Here is an article on olive oil polyphenols. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4926377/ You know the quality of oil is variable. Even the expensive stuff may not be the best. They could be laughing about what they export, but this happens with many products. I have heard that the evo has the most polyphenols, using it like you do as a dressing or dip. This article is interesting but ends in the typical way calling for more studies. There is also some Vitamin E in it but not a large amount.

Answer (score -1):

Good Question!

Here we all know, the excess of everything is bad. If your `larger quantity` means the use of 1-2 TBSP of olive oil in the breakfast time and then in the dinner time is completely fine. The effect of oil on your body totally depends on your way of intake- this also includes the quantity. You also need to take care of your other intakes.

For example, If you are taking olive oil in warm milk before going to bed then the effect would be different on your body. If you are just pouring some oil onto the food then the effect would be different. What else are you taking which includes fats, and similar nutrients?

There are many benefits of olive oil that we cannot even count. But it also depends on how pure is your Olive OIL is. if it is not pure then it is very harmful to you to take in high amount. if it is pure and you are sure, you still wanna use good amount then you should be doing some exercise in order to consume it properly.

Comment: *you should be doing some exercise in order to consume it properly.* How does doing exercises clean contaminated sources of olive oil?